# Add literal Tab in answer?

Tags: support

So, as a relative neophyte here, I was all excited to share my [nifty answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695349/140192) to a question about making PDF files reproducible, but when posting it, I found that tex.stackexchange.com converted my <kbd>Tab</kbd> character to spaces, which made my answer seem to be inexplicably broken to anyone who cuts and pastes it into a file.

I can sort of see why other stackexchange sites might want to untabify everything, but it doesn't seem to make sense here. Is there a workaround for this? Or maybe some toggle switch that the admins of tex.stackexchange.com can flip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are standardised by both plain TeX and LaTeX to spaces, so for almost all cases there is not really a need for 'us' to worry'. However, tab replacement is not controlled 'locally' for the site in any case: this is something that only the Powers can alter. I suspect it may be a feature of the editor system ...

Answer (score 2):

You must use the HTML entity `&#9;` for the tab character. Since this only works in HTML, not MarkDown code blocks, you'll also need to use `&lt;` for the <kbd><</kbd> character.

For example, if you select this, you can see it has embedded tabs:

```
<A>					<B>
```

The above can be written on stackexchange as

```
<pre><code>&lt;A>&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&lt;B></code></pre>
```

---

Note: Thanks and credit goes to @ulrich-diez who provided this brilliant answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508103/140192.